# Why does the order of redirection assignments matter for a proxy file descriptor

Tags: shell, redirect, posix, file-descriptor

I am learning about redirections in shell right now (reading the posix standard).
I played a little with the different operators and think I get the hang of it. In the following example, I am creating a new file descriptor and use that as a proxy.
What I cannot really fathom is why this works:

```
exec 6<> ~/Desktop/test && ls 6>&1 2>&6 1>- | say
```

but this not:

```
exec 6<> ~/Desktop/test && ls 2>&6 6>&1 1>- | say
```

The desired result is to read out any errors that occur during `ls`.

Comment: According to POSIX shell syntax, redirection operations are processed from left to right. That's why a different order may have a different effect.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. In the second snippet I assign standard error to the test-file and then assign the file descriptor 6 to standard output. I misunderstood how & exactly works.